# Error occurred when python function calling GRASS GIS module and another python function of the same kind

Tags: python, grass

I wrote a python funciton **A** to call a GRASSGIS module from outside, and it ran fine. I wrote another python function **B** containing statement calling another GRASSGIS module and python function **A**, error occurred.

function A:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy
from GRASSGIS_conn import GRASSGIS_conn


def v_edit(map_name, tool, thresh, coords):

    cor = [",".join(item) for item in coords.astype(str)]
    no_of_cors = len(cor)
    i = 0
    while i <= no_of_cors - 1:
        g.run_command('v.edit', map = map_name, tool = tool, threshold = thresh, coords = cor[i])
        i = i + 1
```

function B:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy
from GRASSGIS_conn import GRASSGIS_conn
from v_edit import v_edit


def split_line(line_shape, out_name, thresh, point_cor):

    g.run_command('v.in.ogr', overwrite = True, input = line_shape, output = out_name)
    v_edit(out_name, 'break', thresh, point_cor)



if __name__ == "__main__":


    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], 'etc', 'python'))
    import grass.script as g
    gisdb = 'C:\Users\Heinz\Documents\grassdata'
    location = 'nl'
    mapset = 'nl'
    GRASSGIS_conn(gisdb, location, mapset)
    point_cor = numpy.genfromtxt('proj_cor.csv', delimiter = ',')
    split_line(r'C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop\all.shp', 'tctest', '50', point_cor)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop\split_line.py", line 25, in <module>
    split_line(r'C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop\all.shp', 'tctest', '50', point_cor)
  File "C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop\split_line.py", line 11, in split_line
    v_edit(out_name, 'break', thresh, point_cor)
  File "C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop\v_edit.py", line 13, in v_edit
    g.run_command('v.edit', map = map_name, tool = tool, threshold = thresh, coords = cor[i])
NameError: global name 'g' is not defined
```

And I have tested that function **B** without the statement calling function **A** ran well without error.

I don't know why this happened and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:
Have the from `import grass.script as g` in the top level imports i.e. file 1 (`function A` - `v_edit.py`) will be:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy
from GRASSGIS_conn import GRASSGIS_conn
import grass.script as g

def v_edit(map_name, tool, thresh, coords):

    cor = [",".join(item) for item in coords.astype(str)]
    no_of_cors = len(cor)
    i = 0
    while i <= no_of_cors - 1:
        g.run_command('v.edit', map = map_name, tool = tool, threshold = thresh, coords = cor[i])
        i = i + 1
```

---

**Cause**:
You have `g` defined (imported) in `if __name__ == "__main__"` block - which doesn't count as part of file code.

Read this - [what does if **name** == "**main**" do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/15789709#15789709).